# Submenu not showing - overflow hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, submenu

my problem is that I got 3 submenus in the third nav named "**Productos**", but they are not showing.

I think maybe the error got something with the jQuery plugin kwicks... making it overflow:hidden;

I'm kinda new so I will appreciate your help ^^

[Here is the link to the website](http://dinterweb.com/reasa/)

Edit: I remove the kwicks and I can see the submenu but I need the kwicks, Is there someway to bypass that??

Comment: you should the kwicks plugin and try independently otherwise. I think that should work.

Comment: I disable the plugin and I can see the menu but I need the kwicks, Is there a way I can bypass that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome I can see half of your first menu that has a text like "Maquinaria".
I think that the menu is going to show inside its container.

Have you tried setting an higher z-index?

I have also checked with Developer tool and the overflow is correctly set to visible.

EDIT:

This is the code generated at runtime:

```
<li id="kwick_3" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; left: 225px; width: 200px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; display: block; " class="active">
    <a class="headlink" href="#">Productos<h3>Nuestros productos</h3></a>
    <ul style="visibility: visible; display: block; ">
       <li><a href="#">Maquinaria pesada</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Transporte</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Agroindustria</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The UL element has an overflow (x and y) set to visible. but the parent LI element has its overflow (x and y) set to hidden

Comment: I try what you say, z-index to 9999 and nothing... and yes I did put overflow to visible but I think the kwicks turn that into hidden... but thanks for your answer ^^

Comment: No. It is set to visible. If you have chrome you can use Developer tool to see what is the computed style of an element at runtime. It show you change dynamically done to the DOM and more... ;

Answer (score 1):

Your `li#kwick_3` element has `overflow: hidden` set in html, which overrides `overflow:visible` set in css. When I disable this setting in firebug, submenu options show themselves.

You can also set `overflow: visible !important` for `#kwick_1, #kwick_2, #kwick_3, ..` in your `style.css` to override setting in html (again, works for me in firebug).

Comment: exactly what I wanted to say :)